# sinselect top n records (other than using orderBy and rownum)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, aggregate-functions

How do I select the top 3 count from, say, the table below. I know it can be done by using combination of `ORDER BY` and `ROWNUM`, but I want it to display in such a way that:
If the ID with count number is same, all ID with same count shall be display together

```
ID          COUNT
----------- -----------------
a            4
b            2
c            3
d            2
e            1
```

I'm using Sql plus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is with the `dense_rank()` analytic function:

```
select id, count
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by count desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic query

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  mytable a
WHERE   
  3 > ( SELECT count(1) FROM mytable b where b.count > a.count)
```